# Not able to remove disable property of button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, checkbox

I have  a set of check-boxes only one of them will be checked at a time. (I need check-boxes here not radio buttons). There is a disabled button in the same page.

I am trying to remove the disabled property of button upon clicking a checkbox.

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="me" data-btname="xxxx" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="me" data-btname="xxxx" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="me" data-btname="xxxx" />

<input type="button" name="aa" id="xxxx" value="this is me" disabled />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.me').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    var buton_namee = $(this).attr('data-btname');
    //alert(buton_namee);
    $('#buton_namee').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/8konjjq1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8konjjq1/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retrieving `id` from `data-btname`, so to put it in a selector like below

```
$('#' + buton_namee).removeAttr('disabled');
```